# Having issues with ANDROID_ID

Tags: java, android, uuid, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm trying to get ANDROID_ID working in my appn but I'm getting odd behavior in my emulator and also on hardware.

an extract from my app.

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

public class RssActivity extends ListActivity {

final String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID); 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("UUID", android_id);
```

Now in my emulator the app opens but then seems to freeze and does nothing, I don't even get my "UUID" debug message.

On my phone i just get a `"the application has stopped unexpectedly" OS 2.3.3`

Any ideas, am i implementing this wrong?

If i remove `"final String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);"` then the app works fine on both emulator and hardware - so the problem must be located here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only declare the variable before `onCreate` and then get device id on the `onCreate`. Then Your null pointer exception will be solved.

This happens because of **getContentResolver()** needs fully initiated Context(Activity).

```
String android_id; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tst);
    android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.d("UUID", android_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);`